# Waiting for all Tasks in Async to complete

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to run 10 processes simultaneously and when they finish I want to display a `messagebox`. The `UI` should remain responsive.

I have this function (`MultiProcessImages`) which displays a message before all the `images` finish:

```
 'Start multi processing of images
    Public Shared Async Function MultiProcessImages() As Task
        'Create a task factory and add 10 process one for each ending image number
        Dim t As Task = Nothing
        For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            Dim temp_i As Integer = i
            t = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() Cheque.CopyBinaryValueToFile(temp_i))
            Await t
        Next
    End Function
```

Then I created another function which makes the `UI` unresponsive and also the processing does not seem to be multitasking (which means it does not perform all the actions of the `CopyBinaryValueToFile` in parallel but only for each task number):

```
Public Shared Async Function MultiProcessImages**2**() As Task
        Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            Dim temp_i As Integer = i
            tasks.Add(Cheque.CopyBinaryValueToFile(temp_i))
            ' tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() Cheque.CopyBinaryValueToFile(temp_i)))
        Next
        Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
        MessageBox.Show("done")
    End Function
```

Any ideas how to make it behave like I have it in the first function but wait until all the processes finish to display a message?

**EDIT**

I'm calling the function like this:

```
 Private Async Sub cmdConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdConvert.Click
        'Await Cheque.CopyBinaryValueToFile()
        '{Time count
        Dim start_time As DateTime
        Dim stop_time As DateTime
        Dim elapsed_time As TimeSpan
        start_time = Now
        '}

        Await Cheque.MultiProcessImages2()

        '{Time count
        stop_time = Now
        elapsed_time = stop_time.Subtract(start_time)
        MessageBox.Show("elapsed_time = " & stop_time.Subtract(start_time).ToString & Environment.NewLine _
        & elapsed_time.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.000000"))
        '}
    End Sub
```

Comment: show where the method is being called from (button click etc)

Comment: @Ric I have just added the calling function

Comment: what does `Cheque.CopyBinaryValueToFile()` do?

Comment: @Ric It downloads a blob from the database, unzips it, resizes images, inserts the resized images to a table, deletes the extracted and resized files. It takes a number because it processes all the records from the database where recordid = ends with the dynamic number 0-9

Comment: Here is a quote from MSDN: "An async method that’s a Sub procedure or that has a void return type can’t be awaited, and the caller of a void-returning method can't catch any exceptions that the method throws." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx you maybe better off doing:  `tasks.Add(Task.Run(Function() Cheque.CopyBinaryValueToFile(temp_i)))`

Comment: @Ric It looks like it's working like this. You can add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85112/discussion-between-ric-and-alwaysvbnet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code and the implementation of `Cheque.CopyBinaryValueToFile()`, the following may help you resolve the issue of UI being blocked:

Within `MultiProcessImages2()`:

`tasks.Add(Task.Run(Function() Cheque.CopyBinaryValueToFile(temp_i)))`